# Explicit notation of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to give the specific form of the matrix

$$
A=(a_{ij})_{1\le{i,j}\le{n}} \\
a_{ij}=\delta_{i+1,j}
$$

which would be

$$
     \begin{pmatrix}
     0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
     \vdots  & \vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0    
     \end{pmatrix}
$$

Furthermore I have to give a formula for the entries of the following matrix

$$
    B= \begin{pmatrix}
     4 & 5 \\
     5 & 6 \\    
     \end{pmatrix}
$$

which would be

$$
b_{ij}=i+j+2
$$

Are both of the results correct?

Comment: Yes -- they are.